# How to do one where BEFORE multiple inserts in SQL Server

Tags: sql, nhibernate, sql-server-2008

I'm doing a multiple insert in SQL Server using UNION ALL between the inserts. In the last part of the query I have a WHERE clause. Now it seems that that the WHERE clause is executed before every statement, but I only want the  WHERE to be executed one time. If the WHERE clause has a result then none of the inserts should be executed.

For illustration, insert some persons into a table, if any records exists with one of the defined ages none of the inserts should be executed.

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
    select 1, 33,john UNION ALL
    select 2, 28,james UNION ALL
    select 3, 20,Harry UNION ALL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable where age in(22,28,30))
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
(id, age, name)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 33 AS age, 'john' AS name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 28, 'james'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 20, 'Harry' 
) T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE age IN (22, 28, 30))
```